# How to get mathematica to work out residues of $f(z)=-\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\frac{2n/z}{z^{2n}-1}$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, complex

Using the function,

$f(z)=-\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\frac{2n/z}{z^{2n}-1}$,

should give residues as follows:

$
\begin{align}
 \
&\left(\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}(f(z))+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1}(f(z))\right) =
&\left(2n-\frac23(2n^2+1)\right)
\end{align}
$

However when I use the Mathematica `Residue[]` function:

```
Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n))), {z, -1}]
Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n))), {z,  0}]
```

I do not get the same result.

What do I have to do to get Mathematica to work out these residues?

Comment: For me the second line, `Residue[f,{z,0}]` doesn't evaluate, only for particular `n=1,2,...`.  Even computing for particular `n` (I get `Residue[f,{z,0}]==2n`), the sum doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: That's not all the residues.

Comment: @josh true there are many residue 1

Comment: @onepound in the original version of my answer there was a shift in the number `n` which was wrong and is fixed now. Sorry for the confusion. The updated version works fine :-) You can see the exact agreement with the result in the OP. Please note, that to get that result $n>0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
f[z_] := -((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n)))
```

we generate data

```
Table[Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, -1}] + 
  Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, 0}], {xx, 1, 17, 1}]
```

> [image: res]

and then

```
FindSequenceFunction[{0, -2, -(20/3), -14, -24, -(110/
      3), -52, -70, -(272/3), -114, -140, -(506/3), -200, -234, -(812/
      3), -310, -352}, n] // FullSimplify
```

> [image: correct]

Edit:

*Discussing the minimum number of terms*

The following seems to be the minimal choice

```
FindSequenceFunction[
   Table[Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, -1}] + 
     Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, 0}], {xx, 1, 4, 1}], n] // FullSimplify
```

For `{xx,1,3,1}` `Mathematica` does not return the formula.

Answer (score 6):

In V13:

```
Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n))), {z, -1}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
```

> ```
> (*  -(2/3) (1 + 2 n^2)  *)
> ```

```
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, 
 Simplify@
  SeriesCoefficient[
   Normal@
    Series[-((2 n (-1 + z)^2)/(z (1 + z)^2 (-1 + z^(2 n)))), {z, 
      0, -1}], {z, 0, -1}]
 ]
```

> ```
> (*  2 n  *)
> ```

Not sure why `SeriesCoefficient` fails on the given function when `Series` succeeds. (Bug?)

Answer (score 2):

Following bmf's idea:

```
Total[Map[FindSequenceFunction[#, n] &, 
  Transpose[
   Table[Map[
     Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (2 n)/(
        z (-1 + z^(2 n))), {z, #}] &, {0, -1}], {n, 1, 17}]]]]
 (*2 n - 2/3 (1 + 2 n^2)*)
```

Comment: thanks for the additional contribution. Why {n, 1, 17} is this range chosen?

Comment: @onepound you need enough input data for the `FindSequenceFunction` command to work. There's no standard for how many terms you need and in this case the number `17` is not the minimum. For instance you can check on your machine that `FindSequenceFunction[
   Table[Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, -1}] + 
     Residue[f[z] /. n -> xx, {z, 0}], {xx, 1, 4, 1}], n] /. 
  n -> n + 1 // FullSimplify` yields the right answer. `f[z]` is the function from the OP. See also my edit

Answer (score 1):

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n))), {z, -1},Assumptions->n\[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `-2/3 (1 + 2 n^2)`

Let us check it through

```
Table[Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + 
   z^(2 n))), {z, -1}]+ 2/3*(1 + 2*n^2), {n, 1, 5}]
```

> `{0,0,0,0,0}`

Comment: yes that works on version 12 too, thanks. Not sure if anything can be done about residue at 0 other than to inspect the function visually for the answer.

Comment: Agreed. `Residue[-((z - 1)/(z + 1))^2 (((2 n)/z)/(-1 + z^(2 n))), {z,0},Assumptions->n\[Element] PositiveIntegers]` fails.